# Change shape mouse to shape green circle in a Swing application?

Tags: java, swing

I want code to change default mouse shape to a green circle when click the button in netbeans java.

Comment: see the Component.setCursor, Cursor, and MouseListener.MouseEnter/MouseExit

Answer (score 1):

Look for these following events `MouseListener.MouseEnter` and `MouseListener.MouseExit`.

You change a cursor using `java.awt.Cursor` with this command:

```
setCursor(Cursor cursor);
```

You can choose from lots of various cursors. If you want your own cursor, try this ot (not tested):

```
setCursor(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
   new ImageIcon("image.png").getImage(), 
   new Point(0,0),"Your cursor")
);
```

Comment: me not need this shape i want to generate green circle to become the shape of mouse to laser pointer

Comment: no efficiency when add any image i want to generate green circle

Answer (score 0):

`Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
      File cursorFile = new File("f:\\image.png");
      Image image = toolkit.getImage(cursorFile.getAbsolutePath());
      Point hotspot = new Point(0, 0);
      Cursor cursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image, hotspot, "Stone");
      setCursor(cursor);`

[this tool in power point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSTdQ.jpg)

[I want the mouse pointer the same of p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQPLN.png)